# Hide element tr in table with css

Tags: html, css, dom

I try hide the element  inside table using css , the problem no really works and hide  element , my code it's the next:

```css
.table_cols {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  margin: auto;
}
.td_cols {
  width: 20%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: green;
}
.table_scale {
  display: none;
}
.table_scale_end {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<table class="table_cols">

  <tr>
    <td class="td_cols">Col 1</td>
  </tr class="table_scale_end">

  <tr class="table_scale">
    <td class="td_cols">Col 2</td>
  </tr class="table_scale_end">

  <tr class="table_scale">
    <td class="td_cols">Col 3</td>
  </tr class="table_scale_end">

  <tr class="table_scale">
    <td class="td_cols">Col 4</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

My idea it´s hide elements with classes called **table_scale** and **table_scale_end** , for example fot other reolutions i can display this clases and the col see one to one under to the other and this works , the problem it´s with full screen only show for example one col , the idea it´s use this code with media queries and turn on or turn off the  tags with other resolutions , but no get works

For full resolution : http://jsfiddle.net/kpwaLat8/
( Here must show the cols one beside the other but not show)

For for example no full resolution activate the classes and works : http://jsfiddle.net/r1t4qybs/

The Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I adjusted your HTML to properly use the `table`, `tr` and `td` tags based on your designations of each column:

```
<table class="table_cols">
    <tr>
        <td class="td_cols">Col 1</td>
        <td class="td_cols table_scale">Col 2</td>
        <td class="td_cols table_scale">Col 3</td>
        <td class="td_cols table_scale">Col 4</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is the updated CSS:

```
.table_cols {
    width:100%;
    height:200px;
    margin:auto;
}

.td_cols {
    width:20%;
    height:200px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {   //set the maximum width at which you want to show all 4 columns - anything less than that will hide columns 2, 3 and 4
    .table_scale {
        display:none;
    }
}
```

**[JSFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/kpwaLat8/3/)** (try resizing the result screen to see the media query in action)

Answer (score 0):

You can also refer below link:-

http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html

http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Use these code instead of yours:

```
      @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {

            .table_scale
            {
             display:none;
            }

           .table_scale_end
            {
             display:none;
            }
        }

        /* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
        @media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1024px) {
            .table_scale
            {
              display:block;
            }

            .table_scale_end
            {
              display:block;
            }
        }
```